# Printing a username by id via php from MySQL

Tags: php, html

I am trying to print a username from a database via his id. I want the id to be choosen by entering it to a input form, but it does not work. any clues why?

```
<div>
      <p><u>Anzeigen eines Users mit Eingebafeld für die id</u></p>
      <form method="post1" >
        <p>Zu suchende id:</p> <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="Buttonid" value="Suchen" class="btn btn-primary" >
     </form>
    </div>
    <div>
     <?php
       /*ini_set('display_errors', 0);*/
       $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "test", "test", "test");
       if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
         print "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
       }
       $id = @$_POST1;
       $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT username FROM user WHERE id = $id");
       $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
         print '<p>' . $row['username'] .'</p>';
     ?>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What `post1` doing here in `<form method="post1" >` ??

Comment: could you specify what you mean?

Comment: `<form method="post1" >` should be `<form method="POST">` and `$id = @$_POST1;` should be `$id = $_POST['id'];`

Comment: "it does not work" - could you maybe elaborate on this? What happens instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you want something like this:

```
<div>
      <p><u>Anzeigen eines Users mit Eingebafeld für die id</u></p>
      <form method="post" >
        <p>Zu suchende id:</p> <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="Buttonid" value="Suchen" class="btn btn-primary" >
     </form>
    </div>
    <div>
     <?php
       /*ini_set('display_errors', 0);*/
       if (isset($_POST['id'])){
         $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "test", "test", "test");
         if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
           print "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
         }
         $id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
         $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT username FROM user WHERE id = $id");
         $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
         print '<p>' . html_entities($row['username']) .'</p>';
      }
     ?>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Note the changes:

- post1 --> post
- `@$POST1` --> `$_POST['id']`, No clue where you saw this weird code..
- adding `real_escape_string` to make sure the entered id is not SQL injection, you can also cast it to int.
- adding `html_entities` to be sure username is XSS safe.

The variables in the form are captured in the `$_POST` array when the method of the form is set to `post`. Note also that I check if this array has a value for the `id` because the php code will be executed whenever the form loads, even if the form was not submitted yet.

Comment: A good answer would explain what was changed, and *why* it was changed as well - codedumps like this would most likely not learn anyone of the issue, even if using this code solved their issue.

Comment: Don't worry, I'll look over what has changed, as I need to understand it.

Comment: I'd opt more on using `isset()` against their submit button and using `!empty()` for the id. and hoping their `WHERE id = $id` isn't a string lol

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' on the line of the first if

Comment: @StefanBoguth, sorry forgot a `)`.

Comment: I see, could have figured that out on my own :D

Comment: No problem :), I hope my codes help you understand how it works, and makes it work.

Comment: I'll test it on monday and come back here to share the results I got! :D

Answer (score 1):

You realy need to be carefull about `$_POST` and cleanup all mess there. Also will be good to use prepared statemant but here is one good solution to be sure is safe and to work properly.

```
<?php
       /*ini_set('display_errors', 0);*/
   $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "test", "test", "test");
   if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
     die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
   }
   if(isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id']))
   {
        $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
                 'options' => array(
                 'default'   => 0
              );
        // to be shure that is number
        $id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/Ui", "", $id);

        $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT username FROM user WHERE id = {$id} LIMIT 1;");
        $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
        if(isset($row['username']) && !empty($row['username'])) 
            print '<p>' . $row['username'] .'</p>';
        else
            print '<p>No username</p>';
   }
 ?>
```

Is not ideal but you will understand, I just change your code.

Comment: `$id = ((int)$_POST['id']);` that should theoretically read as `(int)$_POST['id']` as that may fail. Plus, `int` isn't the best to test against a possible entered string. for example `a123` will pass as `(int)`. It's best to use `ctype_alnum()` IMHO. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php

Comment: OK that is true but there can be used `filter_input()` for quick solution. I know but I just suggest that. I will update with `filter_input()`

Comment: Yes, that's another option. Personally, I'm not a big fan of those filters, as they have failed me on many occasions. They're ok, but they have their pros and "cons" ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I have my own filter what protect me many times. PHP filters are not realy secure.

Comment: Well, it's not that they're not secure (they're ok), it's just that their email filter for example, fails on `email@example.c`. I always use a regex, since I can use it for both JS/PHP. The rest of their filters are ok though.

Comment: yeah `filer_var()` also not support longer-name domain like .global, .info etc. regex is best for that.